# django social auth with custom user model is not working

Tags: django, django-socialauth

i am trying to implement django social auth in my project and i am having trouble integrating it with my custom user model. Whenever i try to login to facebook, it is throwing an error and always re-directing to LOGIN_ERROR_URL Page.

My settings.py file looks like below.

```
FACEBOOK_APP_ID              = 'xxxxx'
FACEBOOK_API_SECRET          = 'xxxxx'
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
   'social_auth.backends.facebook.FacebookBackend',
   'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)

SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE = (
  'social_auth.backends.pipeline.social.social_auth_user',
  'social_auth.backends.pipeline.associate.associate_by_email',
  'social_auth.backends.pipeline.misc.save_status_to_session',
  'social_auth.backends.pipeline.user.create_user',
  'social_auth.backends.pipeline.social.associate_user',
  'social_auth.backends.pipeline.social.load_extra_data',
  'social_auth.backends.pipeline.user.update_user_details',
  'social_auth.backends.pipeline.misc.save_status_to_session',
)

LOGIN_URL = '/user/login_register/'
LOGIN_ERROR_URL = '/user/login_register/'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = '/'

SOCIAL_AUTH_COMPLETE_URL_NAME = 'socialauth_complete'
SOCIAL_AUTH_ASSOCIATE_URL_NAME = 'socialauth_associate_complete'
SOCIAL_AUTH_RAISE_EXCEPTIONS = False
SOCIAL_AUTH_FORCE_POST_DISCONNECT = True
SOCIAL_AUTH_USERNAME_IS_FULL_EMAIL = True

SOCIAL_AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'myapp.MyUser'
FACEBOOK_EXTENDED_PERMISSIONS = ['email']

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'myapp.MyUser'
```

And my custom user model is defined as below (just uses e-mail and doesn't use firstname, lastname or username)

```
class MyUserManager(BaseUserManager):
   def create_user(self, email, password=None):
      """
      Creates and saves a User with the given email and password.
      """
      if not email:
         raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')

      user = self.model(
          email=MyUserManager.normalize_email(email),
      )

      user.set_password(password)
      user.save(using=self._db)
      return user


class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser):

    email = models.EmailField(
        verbose_name='Email address',
        max_length=255,
        unique=True,
        db_index=True,
    )
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = MyUserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
```

Now when i try to login to my webapp using facebook login, it takes me to the facebook login credentials page and when i enter the login details, it throws me back to the LOGIN_ERROR_URL page. After i enter the facebook login details, it is not creating a new user in my app.

Can anyone help with what i am missing?

EDIT : -

The error i am getting is AuthFailed (Found user data for token) error message from below
https://github.com/omab/django-social-auth/blob/master/social_auth/backends/facebook.py#L107

For more information, my login_resiter.html looks like below.

```
   <h4> Or Login Using </h4>
   <ul>
      <li><a rel="nofollow" href="{% url "socialauth_begin" "facebook" %}">facebook</a></li>
      <li><a rel="nofollow" href="{% url "socialauth_begin" "twitter" %}">twitter</a></li>
      <li><a rel="nofollow" href="{% url "socialauth_begin" "google-oauth2" %}">google</a></li>
      <li><a rel="nofollow" href="{% url "socialauth_begin" "yahoo" %}">yahoo</a></li>
   </ul>

   TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS += (
     'social_auth.context_processors.social_auth_by_name_backends',
     'social_auth.context_processors.social_auth_login_redirect',
   )
```

Thanks

Comment: DSA calls your manager `create_user` method passing `username` and `email` as arguments, but your definition just accepts `email` and `password`. I would try to change that method signature first, and see how that goes.

Comment: Thanks. I added username to my customised model by passing default values and it works fine now.

Comment: @omab: Is there a simple way to change email as primary key in User Table ?